# Timepicker is unable to show with datepicker on html

Tags: jquery

I have problem with Timepicker wth datepicker. When I have Timepicker code, the datepicker which does not show up on the screen. Please help. Thanks.

```
<link href="jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

<script>  
   $(function() {    
      $( "#start_datepicker" ).datepicker();  
   });  
</script>

<script>  
   $(function() {    
      $( "#end_datepicker" ).datepicker();  
   });  
</script>
```

---

This is html code:

```
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Start Time</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="coursestarttime" name="starttime" class="time" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> &nbsp;Finished Date</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="enddate" id="end_datepicker" placeholder="Write the Date to end..."  value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;Finished Time</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="courseendtime" name="endtime" class="time" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
```

It is not showing up on the screen when the time picker displayed.

Comment: where is the code for timepicker and which plugin is used?

Comment: Sorry, I am going to try to add the code on. However, it is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Add `id="start_datepicker"` to start time textbox.

Comment: Thanks. I addd already on my code. However, it is not showing up on the screen. It is still not working on screen. Please help!!

Comment: The Problem is that calender screen coming up. However, the time screen is not coming up on the screen.

Comment: You need to add `timepicker` library.

Comment: Please let me know how I can add on web pager. Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of such js libraries, just search "timepicker".

Comment: I tried it separately, the timepicker was working fine and datepicker as well. However, I got them at same pager. It does not work on.

Answer (score 0):

set proper selector

```
<script>  
   $(function() {    
      $( selector ).datepicker();  
   });  
</script>
```

check this [datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: Thanks for your answering. However, I followed your instruction and the time picker does not come up. Please help.